# My preferences does not show up after pressing settings button

Tags: android, android-preferences

So, I am currently trying to edit the Snake game that android's api provides. I am trying to make it so that after pressing menu->settings->resume, it would resume the game. However, instead of going all the way to resume, after I press settings, it quits and resumes from there. I am using Intents to resume the program.

```
public boolean onOptionsSelected(MenuItem menu){
    switch(menu.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
        Intent prefActivity = new Intent(this,MyPreferences.class);
        startActivityForResult(prefActivity, KEY_RESUME_RESULT);
        return true;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch(requestCode){
    case KEY_RESUME_RESULT:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(mSnakeView.getMode() == SnakeView.PAUSE)
                this.mSnakeView.setMode(SnakeView.RUNNING);
        }
    }
}
```

This is in MyPreferences.class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.snake_preferences);
        resume = (Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.key_resume));
        onPreferenceTreeClick(this.getPreferenceScreen(),resume);
    }

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferencescreen,Preference preference){
        super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferencescreen,preference);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if(preference == resume){
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicity calling the method that resumes the game inside `onCreate()`, which is probably why the game is resuming as soon as you launch settings. I'd suggest not using the method and instead setting up a click listener for your preference:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.snake_preferences);
  resume = (Preference)findPreference(getString(R.string.key_resume));
  resume.setOnPreferenceClickListener (new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener()
                                         {
    @Override
    public void onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
      finish();
    }
  });
}
```

Also, based on your code `onOptionsSelected()` doesn't explicitly pause the game (however the UI should be paused considering that `onPause()` will be called), you might want to look into that.